# Suppress logging when establishing connection to MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, client

When connecting to a MongoDB server, we get these log messages:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T12:14:18.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.30.1.7:37970","connectionId":2943040,"connectionCount":100}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T12:14:18.633+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2943040","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.30.1.7:37970","client":"conn2943040","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"3.12.10"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"amd64","version":"4.14.248-189.473.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"Java/Oracle Corporation/17.0.2+8-86"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-20T12:14:18.667+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2943040","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.30.1.7:37970","connectionId":2943040,"connectionCount":99}}
```

Is there a way to suppress the messages? We've tried shutting off logging, but it doesn't seem to affect these messages.

Answer (score 1):

The `"s":"I"` part means that this is "Severity: Information". Currently this is already the log level with the least information and there is no way (that I found) to decrease it below that.

Quote from the [MongoDB manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.verbosity):

> The verbosity level can range from 0 to 5:
>
> - 0 is the MongoDB's default log verbosity level, to include Informational messages.
> - 1 to 5 increases the verbosity level to include Debug messages.

Since I had a similar problem and didn't find it helpful that the logs were printing into `stdout`, I redirect them into a file.

You can do this in several ways:

- In the MongoDB config file with the key `systemLog.destination` set to "file" and `systemLog.path` for the actual log file path ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.destination))
- With a command line parameter to `mongod`: `--logpath <path>` ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--logpath))

In Docker Compose, this is how you'd configure the service to redirect the logs to a file:

```yaml
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    command: ["--logpath", "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"]
```

Finally, when the logs are collecting in a file, you can use any log viewer tool to view and filter the logs according to your needs.